# Looking for novel about agent with mind wiped and new orders implanted after each assignment

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a science fiction novel featuring a person who has had his memories erased and the orders for some task implanted in his mind.

The idea that intrigued me most was that this person's mind was being erased and newly reprogrammed after each assignment.

I thought it was by Peter F. Hamilton, but cannot identify the book by the descriptions I find online. Maybe it was written by a different author. I'm pretty sure it was published within the past five or so years.

Comment: The description rather resembles Haldemans "All my sins remembered", but that is a lot older (from 1978).

Comment: Five years you say? Was it a novelization of _Dollhouse_? (I can't find any though.)

Comment: @MrLister No. It was space opera, I believe.

Comment: Sounds a little like the idea behind the TV series Dollhouse but the setting is different.

Comment: It's not an uncommon trope, really -- You'll also see it in Chalker's '[Midnight at the Well of Souls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_at_the_Well_of_Souls)' in the character of Vardia Diplo 1261.  In her case, she was reset after each mission and never knew that each wasn't her first.

Comment: @KHW - Also the "Vals" in Chalker's [Rings of the Masters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_L._Chalker#The_Rings_of_the_Master_series), but they were robots specifically designed for it.  And the main character(s?) in his [The Four Lords of the Diamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Lords_of_the_Diamond) series.  He liked that trope.

Comment: @what - Can you give us more description?  What mission was the agent on?  What kind of spaceship did he use?  Something more distinctive.  As KHW and I just mentioned, it's not an uncommon thing - all our links to Chalker (especially the last one) were (to some degree) "space opera with an agent whose mind gets erased", although they're much older than what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you all. @Bobson It seems to me that it was in the Commonwealth Saga or Void trilogy by Hamilton, because I remember the "agent" (if that is what he was) in the context of that setting and story, but maybe I only read the books close to each other and they got mixed in my memory. I live in Germany and bookstores here only have a very small selection of English language SF, and only the most recent publications, so I am quite positive that it was a book published a handful of years ago. It is therefore highly unlikely that it was Dick (whose books I never looked at) or Chalker (too old).

Comment: Hamilton may be springing to mind as there's an idea like that in A Quantum Murder where a murderers' thought patterns are uploaded into other people's brains.

Comment: The first book of Hamilton's Void trilogy, The Dreaming Void, features Aaron. In the beginning of the book he has no memory of who he is, all he knows is that he has a mission and was hired by somebody. As his story opens he becomes an intriguing cog in the machine. Maybe this is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first book of Hamilton's Void trilogy, The Dreaming Void, features Aaron. In the beginning of the book he has no memory of who he is, all he knows is that he has a mission and was hired by somebody. As his story opens he becomes an intriguing cog in the machine.

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, that's the one. I thought it was Hamilton, but the synopses of his books that I looked at (Wikipedia or Amazon) did not elaborate this aspect and I did not recognize the book. Now that you mention the character's name and role, I can find more detailed descriptions online and remember that it was this book I read. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Paycheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paycheck_(short_story)), by Philip K. Dick

> The terms of the contract state that he will work for two years on a
>   secret project after which he will have his memory of the time erased
>   and will be paid an inordinate sum.

It was made into a movie with Ben Affleck in 2003

Comment: As I stated in my question the book I am looking for was published within the last five or so years. I don't see how any work by Dick qualifies. -1 for not replying to the question I asked. +1 for taking the time and making an effort to help me.

Comment: yes, I realize that Paycheck is much older than 5 years, but I've found that sometimes people think that a reprint/new edition print date is an original publication date, especially if they aren't otherwise familiar with the author.